# Space Requirement for ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

System requirements for ***Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*** has a minimum space on hard drive requirement of 25 GB. So is it ok if i only give a **15gb** partition to install it or will it show error?

Comment: You already answered your own question.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I believe it will install on 15gb, however you'll have to be careful with adding software, upgrades (ie. don't ignore them for ages and let them pile up, or you'll run into space problems), maintain your system very regularly etc.  It won't show errors until you're out of space, which will be after the installation I believe.  I'm also assuming desktop (you didn't say, and *yy* is used by *snap* based Ubuntu Core, *yy.mm* for deb based server & desktop releases)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Also can you please tell me whether there will be any problem if my partition is of GPT type.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it in as little as 11.  My Ubuntu VirtualBox install of Ubuntu 20.04 runs well on 11 GB. Not much space left over but runs well for testing.  15 is better if you have the space.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can you please tell me whether i will face issue in installing if my partition is of GPT type.

Comment: I am not an expert. I think that GPT is the kind of partition table.  Not a partition but the part of the software that controls where and how the partitions are accessed.  There are GPT and MS-DOS partition tables.  GPT is newer.  BOTH will work fine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

@Tatsat Dave, my normal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation with Firefox and Chrome browsers and Thunderbird email and normal set of administration tools takes already now 19,5 Gt and in the future years of updates to 20.04 LTS it will take more space. To my understanding type of partition for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS should be ext4.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Think you can help me fix the Ubuntu Installation errors (dual-booting)? I am using Hp Omen?

Comment: What Ubuntu installation errors do you mean ?

Comment: well the question is quite like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241708/failed-in-ubuntu-installation-of-versio