# Failed To Install Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 Alongside Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have tried installing Ubuntu about 10 times. It dosen't install. I first tried Ubuntu 18.04 and then 20.04. Both the times I have got the same screen telling me that system has crashed. So here is how it went for 10 times. First i download the **Ubuntu 18.04.** Then I create a partition in D drive for 50gb. Then I use **balena Etcher** for burning the Pen drive(32gb). 
Then I restart my Laptop (**Hp Omen**), press F10 go to bios change the boot order to USB, find the Grub Menu -- Try without Installing. Then Ubuntu loads, I go for installation and I choose "Installation Alongside Windows". It goes to the end, asks for a restart and hangs. Then i get a black screen for a while with a bunch of errors on it. And it hangs there.
Following are the screenshots of what I get on the screen:
[image]

Then after an hour still this 
[image]
 I left it for hours there and nothing more would happen. So i press the power button for 5 seconds shut down PC reboot it. It gets stuck on this screen.
[image]
Tried doing this procedure for about 10 times with the same result.
Following are the screenshot that i get.
Then I thought, re-download Ubuntu and try again. Did it didn't Work. 
Downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 didn't work. Results are same. So god please help me. Just tell me is there any problem with my system? Or is there any problem in my procedure. And thank you to even read this long question. Just tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Tatsat Dave, before installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows 1.) go into BIOS and check that 'UEFI' or 'UEFI Boot' is turned off and instead of UEFI switch (turn, select) on 'Legacy devices' (or 'Legacy installation' or something similar, exact names may be a little bit diffrent in different BIOS versions); and then 2.) go into Windows and disable 'fast boot' feature.